# MATLAB scrolling plot

Tags: matlab, plot, scroll, matlab-figure

I have an EEG data base that I would like to plot.
The database is a 19*1000*134 matrix, with:

- 19 being the number of channel. On a first approach, I'm working with only one channel.
- 1000 the size of a sample (1000 points for a sampling rate of 500 Hz, i.e. 2 sec of data)
- 134 the number of epochs (number of different 2 second experience)

The idea is to plot epoch n right after epoch n-1 on the same graph. The (X,Y) matrix used to plot this has a 134 000 * not_much size, and I would like to be able to scroll horizontally on the plot, to see individually each epoch.

My code right now, plotting only one channel:

```
fs = s_EEG.sampling_rate;
[channel, length, nb_epoch] = size(s_EEG.data)

display(s_EEG.data, fs, length, channel, nb_epoch)

function display(data, fs, length, channel, nb_epoch)
    figure("Name", "Epoch display")

    for j = 1:nb_epoch
        time = 0.002+(2*j-2):1/fs:2*j;
        epoch = data(1,:,j);
        plot(time, epoch)
        hold on
    end
    hold off

end
```

Current output:
[image: Current output]

I'm completely new to Matlab, and I don't use it well yet, but I would like to find a way to see on the same graph, individually, and at a correct visualization scale, all of my 134 epochs (one color = one epoch above).

Thanks !

Comment: I can't really get what you are asking, could you be more specific? I mean... what are the problems concerning the current result? Should they be all the same color? Actually, using 134 distinct colors on the same plot is gonna be hard, if I get what you mean.

Comment: Ok so I wasn't clear. No I would like to see the first epoch (2 second of data) in BIG on my screen, and then to scroll to the second one, and then to the third. I would like to see 2 second per 2 second of data, on a single figure, because I don't want to open 134 different figures.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14984-scrollplot-scrollable-x-y-axes

Comment: Yep I found this one a bit earlier, and it seems promising, but I still can't get it to work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to something I already had so I tweaked it a bit for you. Basically pass plotData your `data` matrix.  It will plot each of your items sequentially as you already have now.

Pressing the slider will change your x-limits so that you will step through 1 element (epochs) at a time. Clicking in the area will advance 2-epochs at a time.  It currently just displays what you currently viewed "epoch" # is at the command line `disp(['Current Epoch: ' num2str(viewI)])`  However, it should be easy for you to redirect that to a text box on the figure to more readily know which you are viewing ... besides mentally dividing the x-limits by 2.

Use the list box to switch to a new channel which will reset the plot & x-limits.

Call it like this at the command line.

```
>> plotData( data )
```

**CODE: Save everything below as plotData.m**

```
function plotData( data )
% data = rand(19,1000,134);
f = figure('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5]);
a =   axes('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.15, 0.75 0.75]);
s =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','Slider', 'Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.025, 0.75 0.05],...
                   'Min',1,'Max',size(data,3),'Value',1, 'Callback',{@sliderChange,a} );
l =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[0.85 0.15, 0.1, 0.75],...
                   'String',cellstr(num2str([1:size(data,1)]')),'Callback',{@changeChannel,a,s,data} );

stepSize = 1/(s.Max - s.Min);
s.SliderStep = [stepSize 2*stepSize];               
changeChannel(l,[],a,s,data)

function changeChannel(l,evtData,a,s,data)
cla(a);
chanNum = str2double(l.String{l.Value});
sR = 500;  %500Hz
tempData = reshape(data(chanNum,:,:),[],size(data,3)); %Reshape each epoch into a column
tempTime = [0:1/sR:(size(data,2)-1)/sR]' + (0:1:size(data,3)-1)*2; %Build time array
plot(a,tempTime,tempData) %plot all the lines
s.Value = 1; %Rest Slider Position

function sliderChange(s,evtData,a)
viewI = round(s.Value);
disp(['Current Epoch: ' num2str(viewI)])
xlim(a,[(viewI-1)*2 viewI*2] + [-.1 .1])
```

Note: This uses implicit expansion so you need Matlab 2016b or higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It sounds awesome, and perfectly fit to my need! I'll have a look as soon as possible.

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks !

Comment: Second part of my problem (that I didn't thought before...), if you got some more time to help me :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272588/matlab-uicontrol-callback-return-matrix

Comment: @Mathieu  answered the other questions ... mostly.  I can finish it later but have an appointment I have to get to now.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a look !

Comment: @Mathieu no problem.  Just upvote and accept if it helps