# MATLAB uicontrol callback return matrix

Tags: matlab, signals, uicontrol

Original post: [MATLAB scrolling plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250746/matlab-scrolling-plot)

I got a second part in my problem now.
As before, I have a 19*1000*134 matrix that I'm plotting thanks to the nicely answer from Aero Engy on the last post.

I would like to create in my workspace a vector called clean that will have a 134 length.

By default, the value for clean(i) (with i between 1 and 134) will be 1 -- but, if I press a button on the UI interface, the value must get to 0.

My code bellow, just don't give me any ouput. The button seems to work, but when I close the figure, I don't get the vector clean.

```
function cleanData(data);
% data = rand(19,1000,134);
global clean
clean = ones(1,size(data,3));
f = figure('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5]);
a =   axes('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.15, 0.75 0.75]);
s =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','Slider', 'Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.025, 0.75 0.05],...
                   'Min',1,'Max',size(data,3),'Value',1, 'Callback',{@sliderChange,a});
l =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[0.85 0.15, 0.1, 0.75],...
                   'String',cellstr(num2str([1:size(data,1)]')),'Callback',{@changeChannel,a,s,data});
c = uicontrol(f, 'Style','pushbutton','Units','Normalized','String','Not clean',...
                   'Position',[0.85 0.025 0.1 0.05],'Callback',{@notClean,clean,s});

stepSize = 1/(s.Max - s.Min);
s.SliderStep = [stepSize 2*stepSize];               
changeChannel(l,[],a,s,data)

function changeChannel(l,evtData,a,s,data)
cla(a);
chanNum = str2double(l.String{l.Value});
sR = 500;  %500Hz
tempData = reshape(data(chanNum,:,:),[],size(data,3)); %Reshape each epoch into a column
tempTime = [0:1/sR:(size(data,2)-1)/sR]' + (0:1:size(data,3)-1)*2; %Build time array
plot(a,tempTime,tempData) %plot all the lines
s.Value = 1; %Rest Slider Position

function sliderChange(s,evtData,a)
viewI = round(s.Value);
disp(['Current Epoch: ' num2str(viewI)]) %console print
xlim(a,[(viewI-1)*2 viewI*2] + [-.1 .1])

function notClean(c,evtData,clean,s)
num = round(s.Value);
clean(num) = 0;
disp(['Epoch ' num2str(num) ' not clean']) %console print
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Bonus: It would be nice if

- When I press the button "Not clean", the slider change values and increment aswell (Currently, I have to press the button, then the right Arrow of the slider to go to the next 2 secs of data).
- Once I check "Clean" or "not clean" for one channel (one of the 19 rows of the matrix), for the next one, it will skip the "not clean" data (i.e. with a 0 in the clean matrix corresponding to the epoch number).

Thanks for the help, I'm quite new at MATLAB, and even if I improve quickly, I'm far from fully understanding this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the notClean callback I called `clean` out as a global.  I also removed it as an input ... since it is a global it is not necessary to pass it in.

Also I added the code to advance the slider 1 each time you pressed the button.

In your workspace after closing the GUI to see what you marked you just need to do the following at the command line to access your `clean` array.  (Numbers are random things I marked as not clean.

I have to leave right now so I can't address the second bullet about changing channels and skipping the ~clean elementr ... but it shouldn't be very hard.  I will get back here in a couple of hours.

```
>> global clean
>> find(~clean)
ans =
  3  4  11 19
```

**MODIFIED CODE:**
**EDIT: Added code protection at the edges for skipping channels.**

```
function cleanData(data)
% data = rand(19,1000,134);
global clean
clean = ones(1,size(data,3));
f = figure('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5]);
a =   axes('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.15, 0.75 0.75]);
s =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','Slider', 'Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.025, 0.75 0.05],...
                   'Min',1,'Max',size(data,3),'Value',1, 'Callback',{@sliderChange,a});
l =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[0.85 0.15, 0.1, 0.75],...
                   'String',cellstr(num2str([1:size(data,1)]')),'Callback',{@changeChannel,a,s,data});
c = uicontrol(f, 'Style','pushbutton','Units','Normalized','String','Not clean',...
                   'Position',[0.85 0.025 0.1 0.05],'Callback',{@notClean,s,a});

stepSize = 1/(s.Max - s.Min);
s.SliderStep = [stepSize 2*stepSize];               
changeChannel(l,[],a,s,data)

function changeChannel(l,evtData,a,s,data)
cla(a);
chanNum = str2double(l.String{l.Value});
sR = 500;  %500Hz
tempData = reshape(data(chanNum,:,:),[],size(data,3)); %Reshape each epoch into a column
tempTime = [0:1/sR:(size(data,2)-1)/sR]' + (0:1:size(data,3)-1)*2; %Build time array
plot(a,tempTime,tempData) %plot all the lines
s.Value = 1; %Rest Slider Position

function sliderChange(s,evtData,a)
global clean
persistent prevI

if isempty(prevI)
    prevI = 1;
end

viewI = round(s.Value);
sDir = sign(viewI - prevI);  %-1 if going backwards +1 if going forward
prevI = viewI;

if clean(viewI) == 0
    newPos = viewI + sDir;
    if newPos < 1 || newPos > s.Max
        return
    end
    s.Value = newPos; 
    sliderChange(s,[],a)
else
    disp(['Current Epoch: ' num2str(viewI)]) %console print
    xlim(a,[(viewI-1)*2 viewI*2] + [-.1 .1])  
end


function notClean(c,evtData,s,a)
global clean %Call the global
num = round(s.Value);
clean(num) = 0;
disp(['Epoch ' num2str(num) ' not clean']) %console print
%Advance to the next slider position.
if num+1 < s.Max
    s.Value = num+1;
    sliderChange(s,[],a)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood how the global variable works, and I found a way of doing the second part as well, I post it as new answer.

Comment: Hey! Could you have a look about the change I done for the second part ? It created 2 problems that I can't fix. 1, if I press "clean" at the end of the axis (i.e no more step to move to), it crash // 2. The left Arrow on the slider don't work anymore if I have press clean on the slide before.

Comment: @Mathieu  I will take a look and see what I can do later tonight.

Comment: @Mathieu  Try mode modified code out in this answer.  I think I covered the various error cases when marking unclean at the first & last epochs & trying to use the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code working with second part too:

```
function cleanData(data);
% data = rand(19,1000,134);
f = figure('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5]);
a =   axes('Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.15, 0.75 0.75]);
s =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','Slider', 'Units','Normalized','Position',[0.05 0.025, 0.75 0.05],...
                   'Min',1,'Max',size(data,3),'Value',1, 'Callback',{@sliderChange,a});
l =   uicontrol(f, 'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[0.85 0.15, 0.1, 0.75],...
                   'String',cellstr(num2str([1:size(data,1)]')),'Callback',{@changeChannel,a,s,data});
c = uicontrol(f, 'Style','pushbutton','Units','Normalized','String','Not clean',...
                   'Position',[0.85 0.025 0.1 0.05],'Callback',{@notClean,s,a});

stepSize = 1/(s.Max - s.Min);
s.SliderStep = [stepSize 2*stepSize];               
changeChannel(l,[],a,s,data)

function changeChannel(l,evtData,a,s,data)
cla(a);
chanNum = str2double(l.String{l.Value});
sR = 500;  %500Hz
tempData = reshape(data(chanNum,:,:),[],size(data,3)); %Reshape each epoch into a column
tempTime = [0:1/sR:(size(data,2)-1)/sR]' + (0:1:size(data,3)-1)*2; %Build time array
plot(a,tempTime,tempData) %plot all the lines
s.Value = 1; %Rest Slider Position

function sliderChange(s,evtData,a)
global clean
viewI = round(s.Value);
if clean(viewI) == 0
    s.Value = s.Value+1;
    sliderChange(s,[],a)
else
    disp(['Current Epoch: ' num2str(viewI)]) %console print
    xlim(a,[(viewI-1)*2 viewI*2] + [-.1 .1])  
end


function notClean(c,evtData,s,a)
global clean %Call the global
num = round(s.Value);
clean(num) = 0;
disp(['Epoch ' num2str(num) ' not clean']) %console print
%Advance to the next slider position.
s.Value = num+1;
sliderChange(s,[],a)
```

Comment: Nice.  That is what I was going to do for the second part as well.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks !